# Iframe do youtube com o link inteiro

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api

Olá!

Gostaria de saber se há algum iframe ou algo do tipo que eu consiga por o vídeo em meu site, no caso administrável, geralmente os embed do youtube são com a ID do vídeo.
Gostaria de saber se há algum que eu possa colar a url inteira do youtube que funcione na página.
Segue o exemplo do que eu utilizo(lembrando que este eu copio somente a id do vídeo)

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php print $insti->video ?>"></iframe>
```

Pode observar que após a /do embed é inserida a id do vídeo que é cadastrada, só que preciso de algum embed que eu possa estar colando o link inteiro do youtube,
exemplo:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9VIEZhFORE"></iframe>
```

Estive pensando em tratar a URL, explodindo e pegando os dados somente depois do = só que as vezes pode ser cadastrado a URL curta do vídeo que acaba ficando assim: https://youtu.be/9ZyZxgGBfic ai não vai dar certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se isto pega o URL: `<?php print $insti->video ?>` então você pode fazer um `parse` do ID, um bom exemplo no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6556662/1518921) assim:

```
<?php
/**
 * get youtube video ID from URL
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string Youtube video id or FALSE if none found. 
 */
function youtube_id_from_url($url) {
    $pattern = 
        '%^# Match any youtube URL
        (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
        (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
        (?:             # Group host alternatives
          youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
        | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
          (?:           # Group path alternatives
            /embed/     # Either /embed/
          | /v/         # or /v/
          | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
          )             # End path alternatives.
        )               # End host alternatives.
        ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
        $%x'
        ;
    $result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    if ($result) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
    return false;
}
?>

<iframe width="100%" height="450" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo youtube_id_from_url($insti->video); ?>"></iframe>
```

Ele suporta qualquer url do Youtube, incluindo embed e curtas.