# Galera alguém sabe de uma função que considere caracteres especiais como "://" no php sem ser strpos()?

Tags: php

Galera alguém sabe de uma função que considere caracteres especiais como "://" no php sem ser strpos()? 
Ele não procura nas string um caractere comum junto de caractere especial.
Ex:

```
    <?php
    function onhttp($param) {
    $busca = strpos($param, "http");
    return $busca;
    }
    $testurl = "iuuiuhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw";
    echo onhttp($testurl); //Saída: está após 5 caracteres 

    <?php
    function onhttp($param) {
    $busca = strpos($param, "http://");
    return $busca;
    }
    $testurl = "iuuiuhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw";
    echo onhttp($testurl); //Saída: Nada é retornado.
```

Quero criar uma função que verifique se o começo da url conte a string "http://".

Comment: Isso não é verdade: _"Ele não procura nas string um caractere comum junto de caractere especial."_ - e pra saber se o começo é `https://` basta ver se o `strpos( $param, 'https://' ) === 0` (notar os tres `=` )

Comment: E se quiser achar em qualquer posição: `strpos( $param, 'https://' ) !== false`

Comment: Nossa é verdade, grande falta de atenção minha. E essa não é a primeira vez que não consigo fazer algo por não prestar atenção entre o http e https muito obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `strpos` e `stripos` consideram sim os "caracteres especiais", o problema é que :

- Aqui `strpos($param, "http");` você apenas verificou o `http` e na string `iuuiuhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw` existe HTTP, veja:

  > iuuiu**http**s://
- Já aqui `strpos($param, "http://");` você quer verificar se tem http:// mas a url passada é https, ele nunca vai achar `iuuiuhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw`.
- Outro detalhe citado pelo @Bacco é que `strpos` pode retornar números (iniciando do 0) que se referem a posição ou `FALSE` acaso não encontre nada, ou seja no PHP se usar `==` pode ter problemas em diferenciar 0 de false, portanto use `===` ou `!==` nesta função especifica, deve tomar cuidado e de preferencia ler a documentação http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php e ver os exemplos.

Não entendi o objetivo, parece tudo bem confuso e também não entendi porque não deve usar `strpos`, não tem sentido o `iuuiu` na frente das urls, ou você quer verificar ou você quer extrair. <s>se for extrair então simplesmente use `explode`, assim:</s>

```
<?php
function onhttp($param) {
    $busca = explode($param, 'http://', 2);
    return $busca[0];
}

$testurl = "iuuiuhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw";
echo onhttp($testurl); //retorna www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw
```

Se quer apenas extrair a urls HTTP e HTTPS então use `preg_match`, assim:

```
<?php
function onhttp($param) {
    $busca = preg_match('#(http|https)[:]\/\/(.*?)$#', $param, $matches);
    return $matches[2];
}

$testurl = "iuuiuhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw";
echo onhttp($testurl); //retorna www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw
```

Se quer apenas verificar se é uma URL "http valida":

```
<?php
function onhttp($param) {
    return preg_match('#(http|https)[:]\/\/#', $param, $matches) > 0;
}

$testurl = "iuuiuhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw";
var_dump(onhttp($testurl)); //retorna um valor booleano, no caso true
```

Agora acho que o melhor seja extrair apenas o ID do video, **veja esta resposta**:

- [Iframe do youtube com o link inteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116389/3635)

### Embarcar videos

Conforme sugestão do @EduardoAlmeida, se você pretende embarcar os videos em seu site você pode verificar se a sua página esta usando HTTP ou HTTPS, para evitar inserir iframes HTTP em uma página HTTPS, assim:

```
<?php
function youtubeEmbedURI($url)
{
    $protcol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    return $protocol . '://www.youtube.com/embed/' . youtube_id_from_url($url);
}
?>

<iframe src="youtubeEmbedURI('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw')"></iframe>
```

Ou simplesmente omitir o http ou https deixando apenas o `//` da url assim:

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/youtube_id_from_url('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9kaJZw8iw')"></iframe>
```

Desta maneira o navegador vai usar o protocolo que a página estiver usando no momento.

Comment: Linda resposta! Hey, Guilherme! Dá pra você comentar na sua resposta o uso do `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` para verificar se um servidor, por exemplo, o do YouTube está usando SSL? Obrigado!

Comment: Perfeito, bro!!! Ta aí a resposta pra pergunta do OP. Obrigado!!!

Comment: a parte que vc cortou não deixa de estar correta, está bem confuso mesmo. O problema é que do jeito que ele fez, o retorno vai ser false ou zero se a string estiver no começo, pq faltou o `=== 0` pra saber se existe e está no começo, ou `!== false` pra saber se está em qq lugar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme, e obrigado pela prevenção no uso de (!== e ===) ao em vez de (== e !=) nessa situação.

Answer (score 2):

fácil

```
$url = 'http://site.com';

if(substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://')
    echo "A url comessa com 'http://'";
else
    echo "A url nao comessa com 'http://'";
```